# Web application using c#.net Core internal server error 500

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-3.0

Until 2 hours ago my app worked. In postman my server was called and responses were good. I received a notification about upgrading VS2019, so I did. Now every time i send a request to server from postman i get this error:
[image: Server error]

I tried to downgrade to .net 3.0.0 but that didn't work. How can i solve this?

PS: Sorry for the bad title, i'm not good at naming things

Comment: download and install .net core sdk and runtime v3

Comment: Additionally to what @MuhammadKamranAslam said I think you need to restart your app (or maybe even the system), so that the hosting loads the new framework.

Comment: I can't believe i lost 2 hours on this...thank you guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Muhammad Kamran Aslam and @Andre suggested, installing .net core sdk and runtime version 3 and reopening the app(in my case VS2019), did the job.